# Vite Svelte on build dynamic import don't work anymore

Tags: svelte, vite

I have this svelte project where I implemented dynamic imports for the components FileSelector.svelte and TableViewer.svelte. Locally it works but when i build it and put it into an nginx webserver it still tries to fetch the components from the components directory which doesn't exist in the build dist-directory.

Codedescription:
i have an array with the relative paths to the components. onMount I load the component  with the mainComponentsArray with the index 0. When i wan't another component I just change the currComponent variable

[image: error from google dev tools console]

Svelte code that implements dynamic imports:

```html
<script>
    import { currComponent } from './selectStore.js';
    import { onMount } from "svelte";
    import Footer from "./components/layout/Footer.svelte";
    import Header from "./components/layout/Header.svelte";

    let currentComponent;

    const mainComponents = [
        "./components/FileSelector.svelte",
        "./components/TableViewer.svelte"
    ];

    currComponent.subscribe((value) => {
        changeComponent(value);
    });

    async function changeComponent(index) {
        currentComponent = (await import(mainComponents[index])).default;
    }

    onMount(async () => {
        currentComponent = (await import(mainComponents[0])).default;
    });

</script>

<main>
    <Header />
    <div class="flex w-full flex-col items-center pt-5 pb-5 sm:p-5 lg:pt-10 lg:pb-10 lg:pl-32 lg:pr-32">
        <svelte:component this={currentComponent} />
    </div>
    <Footer />
</main>

<style>
</style>
```

if needed vite config:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte()],
  server: { 
    host: true, port: 3000,
    hmr: {
        protocol: "ws"
    }
 }
})
```

if needed svelte.config

```js
import preprocess from "svelte-preprocess";

const config = {
  preprocess: [
    preprocess({
      postcss: true,
    }),
  ],
};

export default config;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import paths probably have to be known at build time for this to work correctly, i.e. the argument to `import()` has to be static.

I would try to do it like this instead:

```js
const mainComponents = [
    () => import("./components/FileSelector.svelte"),
    () => import("./components/TableViewer.svelte")
];
```

Then you get the element by index and call the function to import.